# How to find out the AD Junk present in the device?

Tags: java, android, file, memory-management, storage

I am trying to find out the Ad Junk present (Files which are Downloaded by the AD SDK of other apps).

This is what I have been able to find out till now -

I am loading the list of all the files in the devices and them checking them and grouping them like this

```
if (file.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".temp") )
{
      //Temp Files found                                   
}
else if (file.getName().endsWith(".apk") && file.canWrite()) 
{
     //Apk Files found                   
}
```

There are many other cleaner which find out the junk files present in the Device. Even I am trying to achieve the same. Can any one help me on how to identify whether the file is an AD Junk file or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Delete Junk File by

```
File[] files = getBaseContext().getCacheDir().listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
    file.delete();
}
```

And Put this permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks. but I am trying to delete Ad Junk of other apps. Can you help.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the codebase of some Open Source Cleaner, like: https://github.com/mzlogin/CleanExpert 
or 
https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/android-device-cleaner 
and see how they do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the example is on Kotlin hence it is difficult for me to understand. Can you please post an specific answer.